# Re positioning canvas control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have Grid with three columns and layout is like

radio button | Canvas Control | radio button

For some feature of my application I need to take a screenshot of current view of canvas feature and save into a file.

I am using following method to save canvas to bmp,where I measure and arrange canvas.My problem is after image is saved ,canvas position in original grid is shifted to left,how can I re position my canvas back in grid as it was earlier.

```
 private void SaveCanvasContentToImage(string path, Canvas canvasControl)
    {
        if (path == null && canvasControl != null) return;

        // Save current canvas transform
        Transform transform = canvasControl.LayoutTransform;
        // reset current transform (in case it is scaled or rotated)
        canvasControl.LayoutTransform = null;

        // Get the size of canvas
        Size size = new Size(canvasControl.Width, canvasControl.Height);
        // Measure and arrange the canvas

        canvasControl.Measure(size);
        canvasControl.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        // Create a render bitmap and push the canvas to it
        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
          new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)size.Width,
            (int)size.Height,
            96d,
            96d,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32);


        renderBitmap.Render(canvasControl);


        // Create a file stream for saving image
        using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            // Use bitmap encoder for our data
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();

            // push the rendered bitmap to it
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
            // save the data to the stream
            encoder.Save(outStream);

            outStream.Close();
            outStream.Dispose();

        }

        // Restore previously saved layout
        canvasControl.LayoutTransform = transform;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try your code without the Measure and Arrange? It seems redundant.

Comment: @Clemens If I try to save image without measure and arrange the saved image is cropped from right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may avoid the layout problem by using an intermediate `DrawingVisual`:

```
var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)canvasControl.ActualWidth, (int)canvasControl.ActualHeight,
    96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

var visual = new DrawingVisual();

using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    dc.DrawRectangle(
        new VisualBrush(canvasControl),
        null,
        new Rect(0, 0, canvasControl.ActualWidth, canvasControl.ActualHeight));
}

renderTargetBitmap.Render(visual);
```